# Spring JavaConfig how to map dispatcher-servlet to something other than root

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My ultimate goal is to be able to have multiple servlets running at the same time (ie: one for MVC, and one for WebServices).  Unfortunately, I can't get the servlet to route to the controller when the servlet-mapping is anything other than root ("/").

I would have thought that the following URL would trigger my controller, but it doesn't.

```
http://localhost:8080/Sandbox/Page/Test
```

If I remove the '/Page' from the servlet-mapping, and the '/Page' from the URL -it works fine.

```
http://localhost:8080/Sandbox/Test
```

**Web Initializer**

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebApplicationConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/Page/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServletName() {
        return "dispatcher";
    }
}
```

**WebApplicationConfiguration**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.sandbox.business", 
                               "com.myapp.sandbox.page", 
                               "com.myapp.sandbox.utility"})
public class WebApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Defines a {@link ViewResolver} as a Spring managed bean.
     * 
     * @return the viewResolver
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/page");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }

    /**
     * Registers resource handlers with Spring.
     *
     * @param registry the {@link ResourceHandlerRegistry}
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/view/**").addResourceLocations("/view/");
    }
}
```

**TestController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping({"", "load"})
    public ModelAndView load(final ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        modelAndView.setViewName("/test/test"); // improve this

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is  in these line

```
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/page");
```

because you use

```
return new String[] { "/Page/" };
```

and the first letter are differents.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  The servlet-mappings are related to the InternalResourceViewResolver?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little non-intuitive, but here is what is happening when your hit `http://localhost:8080/Sandbox/Page/Test`:

1. Since `/Page/` is mapped to the `DispatcherServlet`, the task of dealing with request is correctly given to the servlet you want.
2. Once in your `DispatcherServlet`, the original request is used to find a handler. In doing this `/Page/Test` is being compared to your `Controller`, which is mapped to `/Test`. The two don't match, and hence the server responds with a `404`

Update your controller to be mapped to `/Page/Test` and your code should work as expected.